# What is a better way to indicate an optional message reminder when food order is ready

Tags: forms, mobile-web, optional-fields

I'm designing a mobile website for a food ordering service. There is a feature at the last step of the ordering flow where the user can choose to be messaged once their order is ready. This is optional and the user can ignore it if they want.

How can i improve the following design to let the user know that entering their number is optional. However if they don't enter their number they will need to check the collection counter display to know when their number shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Reduce the amount of choices the user has to make at the same time. The first step is to decide if the user wants a notification or not.
- Change the label to make it more obvious: *Send a notification to my phone when the order is ready*

[image: Step 1]

- Only show the mobile phone input if the user wants to get a notification
- At this point, you can make it mandatory to fill out the phone number, and return an error message if it is left empty.

[image: Step 2]

The message about the counter display can ble shown after the order is placed. This way, the user gets an additional confirmation that the order is placed, and gets assured of how to get it when it is finished.

[image: Step 3]

Comment: This is the correct way - progressive disclosure. Only show the user what they need *in that moment*.

Answer (score 1):

I think designing a "better way" is too subjective at this point. Should your users know the field is optional? Sure, but as you have it now there will be some users trying to skip that field anyway. If you really want to highlight that it's optional here's a couple options:

1. Just add the text (optional) to the field heading
2. Change the notification options to: SMS, WhatsApp, No Thanks
3. Move the notification options to a separate step. Users click Place Order, get presented with a screen that says "Would you like us to text you when your order is ready? If not you'll have to check the collection counter display"

Answer (score 1):

Have a 3rd radio button at the bottom

SMS / Whatsapp / I will watch the Collection Counter